# Is there any free OAuth2 provider that can handle specific users only?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I'm planning to use Facebook's OAuth2 because they offereing it as free. But I wonder if Facebook have some kind of configuration that can block unknow users to login, so only selected users can login?
Is that possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible. But you’re free to “reject” them yourself, within your application logic, after they logged in, based on their user id not being already in your database, or something like that …

Comment: (Unless you were to leave your app in dev mode, and added all relevant users as testers to your app. But I think that still requires that they register their account as a developer first, and you are also pretty limited with what you can actually do with an app in dev mode.)

Comment: @CBroe Okej! So when they login, my application (in this case - Java) will check if it's correct email that have logged in. If not - Send to logout?

Comment: Yes, basically that. You can log a user out of your app automatically, via a DELETE request to the permissions endpoint.